# Unable to deploy a dot net core web app to azure app service using (CICD) publish profile from DevOps service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to create a CICD Pipeline to deploy a dotnet core web app to azure app service using publish profile, and I'm done with continuous integration, when I release the pipeline, I could see the following output "Successfully deployed web package to app service". and only packages are getting updated, and I can't see the web app deployed to my azure app service.

I have build the web app using following tasks

1. NuGet restore
2. visual studio build
3. publish artifact

In visual studio build I have passed the following arguments

```
/p:TransformConfigFiles=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployIisAppPath="appservicename" /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:OutDir="$(build.artifactstagingDirectory)"
```

In publish artifacts, I have used the following path to publish
`$(build.sourcesdirectory)`

`/p:WebPublishMethod=Package` ------> is this the reason for getting only packages deployed?? if yes, what I'm supposed to use for deploying the webapp to app service

If I use `/p:WebPublishMethod=MSDeply`, getting an error saying "there is no package found with specified pattern-->xxx*.deploy.cmd"

So, what are the tasks and arguments to pass to deploy the web app to azure app service??

Comment: Could you please have a look into this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56193190/deploy-asp-net-app-to-azure-app-service-via-build-pipeline),may it helps

Comment: Also refer this MS DOC : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app?view=azure-devops#error-no-package-found-with-specified-pattern